# How to restart a process if a condition becomes true in a bash script

Tags: bash

I am using a bash script to run many iterations of a package. I did not write this package and it has the annoying feature that once in a while it seems to just freeze for some unknown reason and will hang until I kill the job. The program writes to an output file pretty regularly (every minute or so from experience) when things are running smoothly so what I would like to do is compare the time the file was last written to the current time and if the difference is large, say more than an hour, restart the current iteration.

I've found solutions with bash for running other commands sometime after the long command has begun, but can't seem to figure out how to generalize this to what I need.

I am looking for something like this:

```
for iteration in {0..100}
do


./(long_command)
while [ $current_time - $last_file_update < $hour ] 
do

  sleep 60

done

if[ (long_command is still running ) ]
then 

   (restart iteration)

fi

done
```

Comment: google about `timeout` command , it will go like `timeout 60 long_command`

Comment: @PS. the problem is I don't know how long the command will take beforehand and I don't want to give a time limit for the command, I just want to check if long_command has frozen and restart if it has

Comment: @PS. maybe freeze is the wrong word. the jobs seems to just hang, I'm unsure what is going on internally. it starts running and after a while just never progresses, which i can track by looking at the output file. if i then restart the job by hand it usually just runs normally and finishes as it should

Comment: you shoud run `bash -x long_command` and see where it get stuck. this will address the root cause. what you are asking either need `timeout` or use of sending process to background.

Comment: So the real question is "How can I check when a file has been (last) written?", isn't it? Or what are you actually asking?

Comment: How to run a command, probably in background, check if the command has stopped writing output and if so restart the command. Sorry if my question wasn't clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've written a little script that creates a child process which represents your annoying featured package. The script itself checks every second whether the file has been modified and acts on it accordingly. The script is quite straightforward, but please ask if something is unclear.

```
#! /bin/bash

MYFILE=file.txt
FILE_MOD_THEN=""
CHILD_PID=-1
MAX_WAIT_SECONDS=2

function run_command_hang {
        for ((x=0; x<3; x++)); do
                sleep 1
                echo "derp" >> ${MYFILE}
        done
        sleep 10
}

function run_command_ok {
        sleep 1
}

function run_command {
        if [ $(($iteration % 2)) -eq 0 ]; then
                echo "Starting hang"
                run_command_hang &
        else
                echo "Starting ok"
                run_command_ok &
        fi
}

for iteration in {0..100}; do

        run_command
        CHILD_PID=$!
        FILE_MOD_THEN=$(stat ${MYFILE} | grep 'Modify')

        iteration_inner=0
        while kill -0 ${CHILD_PID} 2>/dev/null; do
                FILE_MOD_NOW=$(stat ${MYFILE} | grep 'Modify')

                if [ ${iteration_inner} -gt ${MAX_WAIT_SECONDS} ]; then
                        echo "Process ${CHILD_PID} hangs! Killing.."
                        kill -9 ${CHILD_PID}
                        break;
                elif [ "${FILE_MOD_NOW}" != "${FILE_MOD_THEN}" ]; then
                        echo "Process ${CHILD_PID} is active :D"
                        FILE_MOD_THEN=${FILE_MOD_NOW}
                fi
                sleep 1
                ((iteration_inner++))
        done
done
exit 0
```

Comment: Thank you this is great! I was able to modify this to get exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for your help. :)